# DriveApp FileIterator.hasNext() gives me a server error

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to use DriveApp in a Google Sheet script to bring some data from another sheet.

DriveApp keep giving me a ServerError.

I reduce my code to the strict minimum :

```
function myFunction() {

  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('FileName')  

  while ( files.hasNext())
  {
    var file = files.next()
    Logger.log(file)

  }
```

}

But I keep getting the following log error:

> [17-10-02 18:41:21:403 PDT] Starting execution [17-10-02 18:41:21:409
>    PDT] DriveApp.getFilesByName([FileName]) [0 seconds]
>
> [17-10-02 18:47:21:036 PDT] FileIterator.hasNext() [359.626 seconds]
>
> [17-10-02 18:47:21:045 PDT] Execution failed: We're sorry, a server
>    error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 8, file "Code")
>    [359.629 seconds total runtime]

I tried :

- Removing and adding the Google Drive permission for that Script
- Cleaning my browser cache, etc...
- Made sure that both files are owned by me

I am a bit out of my depth here. Cannot figure out how can I make it work.

Comment: Note: FolderIterator functions and getFileById all give me the same error.

Comment: A related issue appeared this morning on the [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67252034)

Comment: I just ran it and I don't get any errors.

Comment: Thanks for trying out. The issue persists for me. (I tried renewing permission as well)

Comment: Also I have not been able to reproduce this issue. As other method, how about using Drive API? The script is ``var res = Drive.Files.list({q: "title='FileName' and trashed=false", fields: "items(id, title)"})``. Before you use this, please enable Drive API at [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced). When this script is run, file ID and filename are returned. When you have file ID, you can retrieve data from Spreadsheet. But I don't know this leads to a workaround for you. I'm sorry.

Comment: That does work for me. Thanks! and I found a workaround for my current case using SpreadsheetApp.OpenById(). But the DriveApp Services are still down for me.

Comment: @HolyPastry - I realise this may seem 2 years too late but are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: I agree with Tanaike, you probably need to enable both the Drive API and Advanced Services. The error should probably also be more helpful...

Answer (score -1):

This happens because the Google Drive API needs to be enabled.  There are a few steps to this.

First, in the script editor, you must click the + icon next to Services.  Add the Drive API and choose the latest version (v2 as of this writing).

Then you need to go to you Cloud console and navigate to the API library, search for Drive, which will bring you here https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/drive.googleapis.com.  Enable this API.

Then you should be good to go!  Happy coding!